# how to fail an excutionStep in synthetics canary

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to figure out how I can fail a step in the canary script without failing the whole execution.

```
// code inside the handler

await synthetics.executeStep('My Step', async () => {
  // have some code here...
});

await synthetics.executeStep('My Other step', async () => {
  // I want to fail this step and only this one
});
```

Using this syntax crashes the canary completely without any run results

```
await synthetics.executeStep('My Other step', async () => {
  // some code here...
  throw 'An Error Occured';

},
// @ts-ignore
    {
        continueOnStepFailure: true,
        screenshotOnStepFailure: true
    }
);
```

[image: Nothig to show the whole thing collaps]

and using `synthetics.addExecutionError('error happened here')` instead of the throw doesn't fail the whole canary (I still get results) but it fails its run result and shows that all the steps are passing.

What I want is to fail just a specific step and see that that step is ACTUALLY failing.

[image: Steps are passing and green]
[image: The final run is shown as failed]

Answer (score 4):

In order to control the pass/fail of Synthetics canary, the validation function needs to return a Promise that's resolved/rejected. You're using an anonymous function for response validation, but the same concept applies.

```
const requestOptions = {
    'hostname': 'hostname.com',
    'path': '/api/v1/endpoint',
    'port': 443,
    'protocol': 'https:',
    'method': 'GET'
};

const validateResponse = async (res) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode > 299) {
            throw res.statusCode + ' ' + res.statusMessage;
        }

        let responseBody = '';
        res.on('data', (d) => {
            responseBody += d;
        });

        // validate the response body
        res.on('end', () => {
            const bodyJson = JSON.parse(responseBody);
            if (bodyJson.item == true) {
                log.info('Check Success!');
                return resolve();
            }
            log.error('item is false');
            reject('item is false');
        });
    });
};

await synthetics.executeHttpStep('Step Name', requestOptions, validateResponse);
```

[This sample code is derived from the 'Multi-step API canary' example in the AWS docs.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries_Samples.html)

As you (and anyone who comes across this) might be able to tell, how to fail a synthetics step is not well documented. In the example AWS provides, you can see that they're returning a promise in their validation functions and then simply using `throw` within the promise to signal Step error when the HTTP response code is wrong, this is functionally the same as their code saying `reject(res.statusCode + ' ' + res.statusMessage)`.

However, if you follow their pattern and simply put `throw 'reason'` in your `res.on('end', ...` function block then the throw method will cause the entire canary's execution to fail (due to scope).

The fix to this is to use `reject('reason')` to signal step failure. If you simply put `reject()` it will NOT signal failure and the step will still succeed.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I was struggling a lot with it